# How can I tell chktex that I have checked the next line?

Tags: tools, syntax-checker

I use [`chktex`](http://baruch.ev-en.org/proj/chktex/) to check my bachelor's thesis for mistakes. I get a lot of warnings and I would like to get rid of them. For example, I have a line

```
\large{\iflanguage{english}{Duration}{Bearbeitungszeit}: \timestart{} -- \timeend{}}
```

which gives

```
Warning 8 in titlepage.tex line 75: Wrong length of dash may have been used.
\large{\iflanguage{english}{Duration}{Bearbeitungszeit}: \timestart{} -- \timeend{}}   
                                                                      ^^
```

I would like to tell `chktex` that I manually checked this line and that it is ok (and should not throw warnings).

For example, I would like to use something like

```
% chktex: manually checked
\large{\iflanguage{english}{Duration}{Bearbeitungszeit}: \timestart{} -- \timeend{}}
```

Does `chktex` have such a feature?

Comment: shouldn't it be warning that `\large` doesn't take an argument?:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is the template I got from my institute. The cited line is from the title page. It looks good and it works, so I don't want to touch it. What would be the correct way to write it? `\large` within the `{...}`?

Comment: well as written the outer `{}` are doing nothing and `\large` applies to the rest of the document (or current group). That may or may not be OK depending if there is any following text or if it should be large, mainly I'm just surprised that anything claiming to be a latex syntax checker didn't pick that up, not saying you need to change the document

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd never heard of `chktex` but `texdoc chktex` says

> 6.1.4   Per Line and File Suppressions
>
> There are many cases in which ChkTEX will give a warning about a construct which, although it
>   usually indicates a mistake, is intentional. In these cases it can be
>   extremely annoying to have this message appear everytime ChkTEX is
>   run. For this reason you can use LaTeX comments to suppress a certain message on a single line. This can be done by adding a
>   (case-insensitive) comment at the end of the line of the form
>
> ```
>                             % checktex ##
> ```

turns out the documentation isn't totally accurate

```
man chktex
```

reveals it should be `chktex` not `checktex` and I can confirm this works:

```
\large{\iflanguage{english}{Duration}{Bearbeitungszeit}: \timestart{} -- \timeend{}}% chktex 8
```

But of course it should have told you to do

```
{\large\iflanguage{english}{Duration}{Bearbeitungszeit}: \timestart{} -- \timeend{}}% chktex 8
```

Comment: @moose http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=3973372#3973372

Comment: @moose your output shows it is warning number 8

Comment: @moose answer updated