# How to ignore "Wrong length of dash may have been used." inside \cite and \newcite

Tags: warnings, vim-latex

I am using `vim-latex` and get several warnings stating **Wrong length of dash may have been used** pointing to a hyphen inside cite or newcite tags.
How to I tell `vim-latex` to ignore certain warnings?

Comment: Hi. Can you include an MWE (minimal working example) so that we know what packages you are using.

Comment: Would the `silence` package be helpful? I use it to get rid of some hyperrep warnings that clutter my log files.

Answer (score 12):

for those that are looking for it just mark the line as checked
Example:

```
\draw[-Latex] (A) -- (B)% chktex 8
```

More info: [How can I tell chktex that I have checked the next line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208374/how-can-i-tell-chktex-that-i-have-checked-the-next-line)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can change chktex to lacheck in the .vimrc file

```
let g:syntastic_tex_checkers = ['lacheck']
```

It doesn't complain about this dash issue.